# Spock stub matching partial arguments

Tags: mocking, spock

I am using spock for my test cases and I am stubbing a class as below, inventryDAO has a method  getUser which accepts a argument of type PersistableKey.

In the main code the argument is created as below

```
PersistableKey userKey = new PersistableKey(1)
userKey.setRepresentedObjectClass(User.class);
```

In my Specification if I write the stub and argument as below, it works fine

```
User collUser = new User(1);
InventoryDAO inventoryDAO = Stub()

PersistableKey userKey = new PersistableKey(1)
userKey.setRepresentedObjectClass(User.class);

inventoryDAO.getUser(userKey) >> collUser
```

But what I really want to do is to be able to pass argument without setting the setRepresentedObjectClass, something like this

```
User collUser = new User(1);
InventoryDAO inventoryDAO = Stub()
    
PersistableKey userKey = new PersistableKey(1)
    
inventoryDAO.getUser(userKey) >> collUser
```

Is it possible to match the argument based on partial values ?

Comment: I do not understand your question with the fragmentary code snippets and ambiguous explanation given. Please update the question to contain a minimal, complete, executable set of classes enabling others to reproduce your problem, instead of having to guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spock supports several kind of [Argument Constraints](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints), when you use an object you are using the [Equality Constraint](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_equality_constraint) which uses groovy equality to compare the constraint argument with the argument from an invocation. If you can't or don't want to change the `equals` method of `PersistableKey`, then you can manually compare the fields that are relevant to you using a
[Code Argument Constraint](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_code_constraint).

```
inventoryDAO.getUser({ userKey.id == 1 }) >> collUser
```

You can also combine a [Code Argument Constraint](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_code_constraint) with a [Type Constraint](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_type_constraint)

```
inventoryDAO.getUser({ userKey.id == 1 } as PersistableKey) >> collUser
```